# Is the word "being" redundant in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

- What is the grammatical role of **being** in the following sentence?
- Is it better If I remove it from the sentence?

> Art has dramatically changed from what it used to be in the past. For
> instance, still-painting was popular in old ages, while visual art is
> nowadays becoming more and more abstract and conceptual rather than
> **<s>being</s>** aesthetic and practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this is something you wrote: if not, please edit your question to quote a source.

As it stands, I would interpret this as deliberate contrast between **becoming**, which indicates a progressive change of state, and **being** which means staying the same.

To paraphrase the sentence, visual art used to **be** aesthetic and practical, but it is not staying like that: it is **becoming** abstract and conceptual.

If that is what you meant, **being** should be left in place.

---

Note that **in old ages** is not idiomatic. It would be better to say **in the past**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about **back in the old days**?

Comment: @a.toraby grammatically yes, but it is quite informal. I don't feel that it fits in a sentence that uses words like asethetic and conceptual.

Comment: I agree. The relevance of "progressive change" is initially introduced by ***becoming***, then reprised / contrasted by ***being***. Both those highlighted terms could be removed, leaving a perfectly natural utterance *without* that "progressive" allusion - but once we've had the first optional addition, it seems more "elegant" to include the second as well.